# Proper way to identify not unique DOM elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to identify using `javascript` elements that have copies of themselves elsewhere on the page (for example in different rows of the same table), given an ancestor element that contains only one copy of the element I'm looking for (for example a table row).

Using `id` is not good because `id` is supposed to be unique across the entire document.

Using `class` makes sense sometimes but I don't think that adding classes for such purposes is a good idea, especially since this usage has nothing to do with style nor with uniform functionality across elements with the same class name.

What I'm doing right now is:

Using `name` attribute for inputs.

Custom attribute (`data-name` / `data-role` / etc) for other elements.

Am I doing it right? Is there a widely accepted standard of how to do this?

Comment: We have a sort of free form dynamic structure that we completely maintain by our own custom attributes - I think it's a great way to go about it, as long as you polyfill your javascript usage.

Answer (score 0):

HTML classes are not inteded solely for CSS but are also used to group elements together using javascript.

To avoid over-complicating a possibly easy task I suggest you give the elements you want to group together the same class instead of using different approach for each element.

then if you want to select these group of elements with a specific ancestor you can go ahead and select

```
document.getElementById("someAncestor").getElementsByClassName("child");
```

If instead, you want to get all elements with the same class and check if they have the same ancestor(possible duplicates). You can store all elements with the same class name and then use a loop to check if they have the same `parentNode`.